# Change wordpress {{meta:field}} value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to manipulate/validate the value that comes through `{{meta:field}}` on my WordPress page. I wasn't able to find any way of doing this.

I know there should be a function for the functions.php where this value goes through before outputting it to the screen. Something like this:

```
function something($value) {
    //validate my things here
    return $value
}
```

add_action( 'function_name', 'something' );

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Please tell me something more, where it values comes from. What plugin you are using etc etc.

Comment: @MayankDudakiya it are wordpress core values